# How can I show details in a dialog instead of loading a new page?

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a site showing [lots of products here](http://50.116.97.120/~amarhost/park_gold)

When you click on the `product details` link for each product it currently navigates to another page. I want that details in a popup / dialog on the current page.

Can you please suggest a way to do this ?

I am using Joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) :

```
$('.class for links').click(function(e) {
    var url = this.href; // get the current href
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    if ($("#dialog").length == 0) { // create dialog if it doesnt already exist
        dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
    } 

    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
         url,
         {},
         function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
             dialog.dialog(); // show the dialog
         }
    );
    //prevent the browser following the link
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that the URL used to get the content should just return the content of the dialog not the whole page